# Nth Business Day of next year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table name as Table_A, which contain Business Day column and Date column.

```
BD  |   Date
----|--------
3   | Aug-03-2017
15  | Aug-21-2017
7   | Sep-11-2017
20  | Oct-20-2017
14  | Nov-20-2017
```

What I want is, next year date with of same date month according to their corresponding BD

Desired Output:

```
BD  |   Date       | Nxt_yr_Date
----|--------------|------------
3   | Aug-03-2017  | Aug-03-2018
15  | Aug-21-2017  | Aug-21-2018
7   | Sep-11-2017  | Sep-11-2018
20  | Oct-20-2017  | Oct-22-2018
14  | Nov-20-2017  | Nov-20-2018
18  | Dec-27-2017  | Dec-26-2018
```

Right now I have written a code, which convert "Date" to next year date then check if it is Saturday then add 2 days, if it is Sunday then add 1 day

My till now code:

```
select
case 
when datepart(dw,dateadd(year,1,(dateadd(day,1,[Date])))) = 1 
    then dateadd(year,1,(dateadd(day,2,[Date])))
when datepart(dw,dateadd(year,1,(dateadd(day,1,[Date])))) = 7 
    then dateadd(year,1,(dateadd(day,3,[Date])))
    else dateadd(year,1,[Date])
end as Nxt_yr_Date
from Table_A
```

but not able make it for BD specific.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not really an answer, but what about national holidays? They often change dates year-to-year.

Comment: You should read about calendar tables. This is exactly the kind of thing they are useful for.

Comment: What's the logic behind BD column? What does it mean "BD specific"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to find:

- the 3rd business day in August 2018
- the 15th business day in August 2018
- the 7th business day in September 2018
- etc.

Here's one way to do it:

```
SET DATEFIRST 7

;WITH
    Calendar(Date) AS
    (
        SELECT      CONVERT(date, '2018-01-01')
        UNION ALL
        SELECT      DATEADD(DAY, 1, Date)
        FROM        Calendar
        WHERE       Date < '2018-12-31'
    ),
    BusinessCalendar(Date, BD) AS
    (
        SELECT      Date
                ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MONTH(Date) ORDER BY Date)
        FROM        Calendar
        WHERE       DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Date) NOT IN (1, 7)
    )

SELECT          A.BD
        ,       A.Date
        ,       CAL.Date                    AS NextYearDate
FROM            #TableA             A
INNER JOIN      BusinessCalendar    CAL     ON MONTH(A.Date) = MONTH(CAL.Date)
                                           AND A.BD          = CAL.BD
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

It uses 2 CTEs to handle the work:

- `Calendar` is a recursive CTE that contains every day in 2018
- `BusinessCalendar` filters calendar to only leave out Monday to Friday, then number those days within each month

All that left is joining against your `Table_A`.

(Note that this doesn't take into account any public holidays, just weekdays and weekends)

Comment: thanks Mr. Code Different, amazing code. Exact result which I want.

Comment: But here could you brief  what background logic get built when we give `WHERE       Date < '2018-12-31' with UNION ALL`, how SQL makes whole calendar by giving just "start date" and "end date", without putting DATEADD in loop.. Please help to evaluate it.

Comment: `Calendar` is a "recursive CTE". You will notice that the `FROM` clause refers to the CTE itself. This answer is not the right place to explain such feature. Here's [one article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) from Microsoft Technet.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
select bid,
       max(case when year(date) = 2017 then date end) as date_2017,
       max(case when year(date) = 2018 then date end) as date_2018
from table_A
group by bid;
```